# Is it possible to serialize and deserialize an object that contain an object as a variable in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to structure my databases, and I was wondering if it's possible to deserialize an object from Firebase RealDatabase with the following structure.

```
public class Profile{
    private String userID;
    private TenantProfile tenant;
}
public class TenantProfile{
    private String name;
    private Room room;
}
public class Room{
    private String town;
    private int size;
}
```

Can the entire object Profile from Firebase be deserialized from a single query?

I just want to make sure that this is possible before refactoring my code and changing the references to the database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could write some test  code to verify this for yourself without having to make any significant changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase database serializes/deserializes any public fields, and public properties that follow JavaBean naming conventions for getters and setters. Since the classes you show contain neither of those, they will not read or write any data.

If you mark the fields as `public` or add public getters/setters, then writing an instance of the `Profile` class will generate this JSON:

```
"userID": {
  "tenant": {
    "name": "the name",
    "room": {
      "town": "the town",
      "size": 42
    }
  }
}
```

And that's also the format you'll need to have in the database to read the value back.